# Applying a tensorflow function to part of a tensor which meets a condition

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a 2d matrix of values with distances from the origin (to be used for a 2D Fourier Transform):

```
s = tf.linspace(0, 10, 100)
x_grid, y_grid = tf.meshgrid(s, s)

t = x_grid**2 + y_grid**2
```

I want to apply a tensorflow function to this tensor which has piecewise behaviour such that, for values below a threshold, one function is used and above another.

In numpy, this could be easily achieved like so:

```
t[t <= threshold] = fun_1(t[t <= threshold])
t[t > threshold] = fun_2(t[t > threshold])
```

However, in TensorFlow, the same operation results in an error: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`.

I've spent a long time looking around the docs and web for a good solution to this and cannot find anything. Has anyone solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by constructing a mask and multiplexing, both with `tf.where`:

```
threshold = 5
mask = tf.where(tensor <= threshold, True, False)

result = tf.where(mask, fun_1(tensor), fun_2(tensor))
```